# How to link virutualenvwrapper with Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have a venv/virtualenvwrapper set up in a directory. After I start working on the venv, i then create a Jupyter notebook inside of the directory, which brings me to Jupyter's localhost browser. I then attempt to import a library, e.g. pandas, which raises the `ModuleNotFoundError`. I would think that if the venv is being worked on, Jupyter would link to it.

Also, I can import global libraries from pip3, just not the local ones in a venv. Is there a way to use the virtualenvwrapper library with Jupyter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out [here](https://anbasile.github.io/programming/2017/06/25/jupyter-venv/)  I had to install ipykernel after activating the venv, then create a projectname:

```
​(venv) $ pip install ipykernel
(venv) $ ipython kernel install --user --name=projectname
```

​
After that, I went back to the Jupyter browser and change the kernel from `python 3` to the `projectname` which is only viewable after executing the second command line above.

This works for both virtualenv and virutalenvwrapper.

The only downfall is installing ipykernel adds a lot of extra libraries to your venv pip3, but I suppose you could just install ipykernel in your global pip3 to keep from installing it in your venv.

Comment: The last sentence about installing ipykernel in the global pip3 does not seem to work. So `pip3 install ipykernel` must be done in the virtual environment.